# Is there a database of all the divine, human and demonic characters in Hindu scriptures and Mythology?

Tags: gods, goddess, epics

We have so many the divine, human and demonic characters in Hindu scriptures and Mythology. Is there a database of all these characters?

If not I was thinking of creating one but I know that this will be an extensive work requiring years of efforts and validation. Any suggestion to how best to start this?

Comment: Swami Factanand  what a name??

Comment: Indeed, we have documented most of the names of the characters that appear in most Puranas already (not of all characters). U can search on Wisdomlib.org  .  Secondly, kudos if u want to start such a helpfull, Hindu encyclopedia. The start can be made from any purans. Every name must be put in chronology with referance in which shlok of which chapter, of which Puran. But, that will be hectic task to read 18 purans and upapurans also, various Sthala Puranas. Wish u luck !